# flutter build apk not running

Tags: flutter, flutter-build

I have tried everything from flutter clean to clearing package cache.
`flutter run --release` works fine but when I do `flutter build apk --release`, it doesn't move further than white screen. `flutter build apk --debug` works as well. I don't know why it won't work with `--release` flag.

Comment: The flutter `build` command defaults to --release.. have you tried without --release flag?

Comment: yes, I have. But it's still not working.